# how to inject params to mongodb @query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have query like this

```
@Query(value = "{'statusHistories':{$elemMatch:{'status':{$in:['PROCESSABLE']}}},'created' : { '$gt' : { '$date' : ':#{#dateFrom}' } , '$lt' : { '$date' : ':dateTo'}}}", count = true)
    Long countMe(@Param("dateFrom") Date datefrom, @Param("dateTo") Date dateTo);
```

How can I inject `dateFrom` and `DateTo` to params of query ? I've tried different combinations `:dateFrom` etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to access by position like `:?0` and 0 being the position of the parameter in the method.

```
@Query(value = "{'statusHistories':{$elemMatch:{'status':{$in:['PROCESSABLE']}}},'created' : { '$gt' : { '$date' : ':?0' } , '$lt' : { '$date' : ':?1'}}}", count = true)
Long countMe(@Param("dateFrom") Date datefrom, @Param("dateTo") Date dateTo);
```